# How to dynamically add table rows in HTML table from value of input textbox

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

The thing here is adding table rows by inputting value on the text box.
i.e. If I input 2 on text box and click on submit, it will add two table rows.
I've been searching for solutions but I can't seem to find an answer, well for now.

```
<form align="center" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="users" id="user_id"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" value="Submit" onClick="addMoreRows()">
</form>

<table id="tbl_id" style="text-align:center" align="center" valign:"top">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var rowsAdd = document.getElementById('tbl_id').insertRow();
  var rowsAdded;
  function addMoreRows(){

    rowsAdded = document.getElementById('user_id').value();
    for(int x=0; x<rowsAdded; x++){

      var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
      newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='user_name'></td></tr>";

      newCell = newRow.insertCell();
      newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='score'></td></tr>";

      newCell = newRow.insertCell();
      newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='points'></td></tr>";

      newCell = newRow.insertCell();
      newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='total'></td></tr>";

    }
```

Where did I go wrong?
Or all of the code are totally wrong?

Comment: `for(int x=0`? Try `for (var x=0`

Comment: @RobG yeah, it's supposed to be var.. thank you also..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few problems with your current code. First and foremost, after clicking submit you are actually submitting the form so you never get to see the result of the javascript - you need to either replace the submit button with a button tag or add 'return false' to the onClick. In the loop you used int instead of var to initialise the loop. Finally, I think you meant to call 'rowsAdd' 'newRow' and place it inside the loop.

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form align="center" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="users" id="user_id"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" value="Submit" onClick="addMoreRows(); return false;">
    </form>

    <table id="tbl_id" style="text-align:center" align="center" valign:"top">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Score</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function addMoreRows() {

        var rowsAdded = document.getElementById('user_id').value;

        for(var x=0; x<rowsAdded; x++) {
          var newRow = document.getElementById('tbl_id').insertRow();

          var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
          newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='user_name'></td></tr>";

          newCell = newRow.insertCell();
          newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='score'></td></tr>";

          newCell = newRow.insertCell();
          newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='points'></td></tr>";

          newCell = newRow.insertCell();
          newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='total'></td></tr>";

        }

      }
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I learned a lot from this. Thank you for it worked! and also thank you for not telling me how dumb I was.. :) I'm still learning though.. :)

Comment: The listener shouldn't be on the submit button at all, it should be on the from's submit handler. Forms can be submitted without clicking the button, so if the listener is on the button, it won't get called. There is also no reason for the submit button or text input to have an ID. Oh, and a TD can't contain a TR, nor is it wise to use *innerHTML* with a table (it's OK to use it for an entire table or the content of a cell).

Comment: @Matthew Sant can you help me with this second question I have? Upgrading to Chrome Apps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478616/getting-data-from-another-html-file-in-chrome-app

Answer (score 0):

You've made a few errors in your example:

1. `rowsAdded = document.getElementById('user_id').value();` - `value()` does not exist as a method with in the DOM object, and you will use a property: `value` instead for all `input/select` elements.
2. You don't need a `for` loop for this, if I understood what you want.
3. `valign:"top"` is not a valid attribute on a `table` element, use `valign="top"` instead.

This is the code which will do what You want to achive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8" />
<title>table insert/row-cell</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addMoreRows() {
    var user = document.getElementById('user_id').value;
    var table = document.getElementById('tbl_id');

    var row = table.insertRow();

    var userName = row.insertCell(0);
    var scores = row.insertCell(1);
    var points = row.insertCell(2);
    var total = row.insertCell(3);

    userName.innerHTML = user;
    scores.innerHTML = '1';
    points.innerHTML = '2';
    total.innerHTML = (scores.innerHTML + points.innerHTML).toString();
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form align="center" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="users" id="user_id"><br>
      <input type="button" id="mysubmit" value="Submit" onClick="addMoreRows()">
</form>

<table id="tbl_id" style="text-align:center" align="center" valign="top">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the score should add to '12'?